# prevent this page from creating additional dialogs

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, input

I am currently working on project and i have requirement to use java script input dialog to take input from user 
see example

[image]

now i want to remove this check box which says that **prevent this page from creating additional dailogs** 
how i can remove this message from alert box

Comment: can you post some **html**

Comment: @user3091574, this is browser prompt input..

Comment: @user3091574 for what purpose my question is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fount the answer

> We have two different things going on here...
>
> I'm suggesting adding a preference to about:config (or user.js in your
>   profile folder).
>
> Copy the preference name dom.successive_dialog_time_limit Open
>   about:config Right-click in the preferences area and choose New >
>   Integer Paste the preference name and click OK Then enter 0 and click
>   OK

for more details chek this link

- [Prevent this page from creating addtional dialogs](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=10737317#p10737317)

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove because it's introduced by browser.

To solve you problem try to employ http://bootboxjs.com/, whit this library you ca do the same by writing:

```
  bootbox.prompt("Enter password please", function(result) {
   // do something whit result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove this as it's a browser security feature. You should probably look at other ways of presenting your dialog - use a modal window instead for example.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do it's IMPOSSIBLE. Since it's a browser functionality.

Anyway I advice you to use a Model-Box.

You will:
- Prevent that from happen
- Beautify your website.

You may want to check this: http://www.fallr.net/ I've used it's pretty cool and easy. Tou have the PROMPT-LIKE example wich returns you something written by the user. You can also have a CALLBACK to some AJAX function for example.

So you can't remove it make that clear for you at least for now.

Dont use alert system boxes they are ugly.. really..

Hope it helped!